Using GCP Workbench Instance new Terraform module, whenever we resize data disk, a new Workbench Instance is created
Using GCP Workbench Instance new Terraform module, whenever we resize data disk, a new Workbench Instance is created. Is there any way to avoid the re-creation of the Workbench Instance using the terraform module, as this is a road-block for us to use the service.
We tried to build the Workbench Instance using the new terraform module. While we increase the Data disk size, it destroys the Instance and recreate a new one.
This recreation is creating a problem for us to proceeds with using the Workbench instance as normally while testing, Instances stores some data which is required throughout the project lifecycle.
We are looking for a solution to enable resizing of disk without having to recreate the workbench Instances.
